# Data not moving with importrange

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I have imported some data into columns A-D using `QUERY` and `IMPORTRANGE` which is sorted asc by column A (Last name). I then want to manually add data into columns E-P. However as the original sheet is updated with new users and those new people are added to my spreadsheet, my manual data stays where it is and then belongs to the wrong person.

So if someone is added with the last name that starts with A, all the names are shifted down a row, but all the data stays in the original row. So Mr. A was added to row 2 with Mr. B's data instead of a blank row.

Is there a way to tie the data together?

This is my current function:

```
=QUERY(ImportRange("Sheet ID","Sheet!A:F"),"Select Col1, Col2, Col6, Col5 Where Col1<>'' and Col6 contains 'Qualifiers' Order by Col1 asc")
```

I want columns E-P of the new names that are added by the `importrange` to be blank and all the data in columns E-P to be shifted down with every person.

Answer (score 1):

this is standard behaviour of Google Sheets. to counter displacement of data across rows you are supposed to implement a simple ID system and use `VLOOKUP` to bring up the right data for the right rows.

[image: 0]

where **`Tab A!A:B`** will be your `QUERY` and **`Tab B!B1:B`** will be your E-P data and ID is the link in between harnessed by `VLOOKUP` formula. also you will need to change `2` to `{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}` coz having `2` will return you only the first ("E") column

Comment: I realize this is standard behavior, so I am looking for workarounds. And I don't know a whole lot about functions, so if you could explain a little more about how to use the VLOOKUP in this instance, I'd appreciate it!